# Accessing Neo4j Desktop from Browser in Enterprise Edition

Tags: neo4j, enterprise

I am currently using Neo4j Enterprise Edition on my Linux machine. However, I would like to access the Neo4j Desktop interface from a web browser to manage and interact with my databases remotely. Any insights, tips, or recommended setups would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Neo4j Desktop (as the name indicates) is for *desktop* environments and has no browser interface. You are probably thinking of the Neo4j Browser, which the Desktop uses by default to interact with a Neo4j server instance. The Neo4j Browser can also be used from any browser.

Here is the documentation for [connecting to the Browser](https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/dbms-connection/). But, basically, you just need to navigate to port `7474` of a Neo4j server's public URL.

For example, if your server's public URL is `http://a.b.c.example.com`, just navigate to `http://a.b.c.example.com:7474` to use its Neo4j Browser interface. Read the documentation if you need more info.